# csh - Loop in all subdirectories and all files of a certain extension

Tags: loops, file, unix, directory, csh

I want to loop through all directories in a particular directory then loop through all files of *.cbl type.   I get a "Badly placed ()'s"

My test code:

```
#!/bin/csh -f
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# comp_etendu                                                                  #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
 setenv src_folder  "/home/userxx/"
 setenv dest_folder "/tmp/comp_etendu"

 foreach d (`ls -d $src_folder`)
        echo $d
        for file (*.cbl)
    echo $file
end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `foreach` instead of for

```
#!/bin/csh -f
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
# comp_etendu                                                                  #
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------#
 setenv src_folder  "/home/userxx/"
 setenv dest_folder "/tmp/comp_etendu"

 foreach d (`ls -d $src_folder`)
        echo $d
        foreach file (*.cbl)
    echo $file
end
end
```

EDIT: removed username